# Extract a subset of a tuple in Scala 3

Tags: scala, generics, tuples, shapeless, scala-3

Given an arbitrary tuple, I want to extract a subset of the tuple.
The signature would look something like:

```
def subset[T1 <: Tuple, T2 <: Tuple](t:T1): T2 = ???
```

where `T2` is a tuple with some subset of members chosen from `T1`.

Using it would look something like

```
subset[(String, Int, Boolean), (String, Boolean)]( ("str", 42, true) ) == ("str", true)
```

I understand that this requires extensive use of match types and typelevel programming. I feel like it be pretty straight forward with Shapeless but I'm missing some functionality from the std lib on tuples vs HLIST.

Comment: It may be worth adding your solution using **Shapeless** so someone can make a parallelism with the **Scala 3** version.

Comment: What would `subset[(String, String, String), (String, String)](("foo", "bar", "baz"))` be? `("foo", "bar")`?

Comment: It doesn't have to compile when the same type occurs multiple times. I basically don't care about that case.

Comment: I guess it's like a filter where the predicate is checking that every elements type exists in T2

Comment: What about something like `subset[(String, Int), (String, Double)]`? (I assume you don't care about that case either, but I just want to make sure)

Comment: Ideally that doesn't compile because Double doesn't exist in T1

Comment: Could you please add to your question how `subset` should work for `subset[(Int, String), (String, Int)]` and other edge cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for typeclasses! (note that the only Scala 3-specific feature required is `*:`)

```scala
def subset[T1 <: Tuple, T2 <: Tuple](t: T1)(using s: Subset[T1, T2]): T2 = s(t)

opaque type Subset[T1 <: Tuple, T2 <: Tuple] = T1 => T2
object Subset:
  given [T1 <: Tuple]: Subset[T1, EmptyTuple] = _ => EmptyTuple
  given [A, T1 <: Tuple, T2 <: Tuple](using s: Subset[T1, T2]): Subset[A *: T1, A *: T2] =
    case a *: t => a *: s(t)
  given [A, T1 <: Tuple, T2 <: Tuple](using s: Subset[T1, T2]): Subset[A *: T1, T2] =
    case _ *: t => s(t)
```

[See it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CXbIdMkUTG6GLlXEQElhxg)

If you want it to work regardless of order, it's slightly more complicated but still manageable:

```scala
opaque type Find[T <: Tuple, E] = T => E
object Find:
  given [T <: Tuple]: Find[T, EmptyTuple] = _ => EmptyTuple
  given [A, T <: Tuple]: Find[A *: T, A] = 
    case a *: _ => a
  given [A, H, T <: Tuple](using f: Find[T, A]): Find[H *: T, A] =
    case _ *: t => f(t)

opaque type Subset[T1 <: Tuple, T2 <: Tuple] = T1 => T2
object Subset:
  given [T1 <: Tuple]: Subset[T1, EmptyTuple] = _ => EmptyTuple
  given [A, T1 <: Tuple, T2 <: Tuple](using 
      s: Subset[T1, T2], 
      f: Find[T1, A]
  ): Subset[T1, A *: T2] =
    t => f(t) *: s(t)

def subset[T1 <: Tuple, T2 <: Tuple](t: T1)(using s: Subset[T1, T2]): T2 = s(t)
```

[See it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/V81KWYuMQfas4XZs4LKKzg)

Comment: This falls apart if they're ordered differently, right?

Comment: @Felix Oh, do you want it to compile regardless of order? Give me some time to fix that, then

Comment: @Felix Let me know if this works for you now.

Comment: That's impressive -- I'll have to read it carefully, but I think this solves my problem!